# Can I use SignalR for Monogame?

Tags: signalr, monogame

Does SignalR client support Monogame? 
I know SingalR support browser clients, iOS, Android clients, but how about Monogame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a difficult question, because it all depends on your specific circumstances, but here's some general guidelines:

- For FPS games (or other games where network speed is essential), you'll probably want a UDP connection (seeing how it doesn't have the same level of network package verification as TCP, making it faster) and then write your own protocol on top of it (to ensure packet validity), to achieve maximum connection speed.
- For strategy games such as Chess or similar games where speed isn't essential, sure SignalR will work great.

Even then, I once tried making a ping-pong game in MonoGame, which used SignalR to inform the clients where the ball was, and in what direction it was moving. And that worked pretty well.

@Edit: After re-reading your question, I've realized you're not so much asking whether it's a viable option, but more whether you can actually use it. The answer to that question is a simple yes. Any platform that supports any kind of SignalR client, can be used with MonoGame.